# Request.Url.PathAndQuery does not get compiled

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I am just following an ASP.NET MVC 5 book and in his code example says add this to a view:

```
@model SportsStore.Domain.Entities.Product

<div class="well">
    <h3>
        <strong>@Model.Name</strong>
        <span class="pull-right label label-primary">@Model.Price.ToString("c")</span>
    </h3>

    @using (Html.BeginForm("AddToCart", "Cart")) {
        <div class="pull-right">
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ProductID)
            @Html.Hidden("returnUrl", **Request.Url.PathAndQuery**)
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Add to cart" />
        </div>
    }

    <span class="lead"> @Model.Description</span>
</div>
```

The problem is in my Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 the keyword Request is marked as red and doesn't compile.   I also have `Resharper` installed and that one thinks I need Ninject.Activation .. This project does use Ninject but not this one

Comment: If I prefix it with: HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.PathAndQuery  then it compiles but I don't know if it is correct or not? and if it will cause problems later on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.PathAndQuery` you reference `System.Web` assembly Version 4, which relates to ASP.NET platform, not ASP.NET MVC framework.

```
public HttpRequest Request { get; }
```

As I said this is code from ASP.NET platform not from MVC framework as explained in details in the next quote from Adam Freeman book.

> The MVC Framework relies on the ASP.NET platform to process requests, which makes a lot of sense because it is proven,
>   feature-rich and integrates well into the IIS application server. One
>   problem is that the classes that the ASP.NET platform uses to provide
>   information about requests are not well-suited to unit testing, a key
>   benefit of using the MVC Framework.  Microsoft needed to introduce testability while maintaining compatibility with existing ASP.NET Web Forms applications and so introduced the Base classes, so-called because they have the same names as core ASP.NET platform classes followed by the word Base.

If I'm not mistaken your example also from his book.

The `Request.Url.PathAndQuery` reference `System.Web.Webpages` version 3 assembly and it is ASP.NET MVC framework assembly, which you could download via NuGet from [this link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages/).

And it use this code:

```
 public virtual HttpRequestBase Request { get; }
```

The core difference that you can unit test HttpRequestBase and cannot HttpRequest. So for ASP.NET MVC it is recommended to use `System.Web.Webpages` assembly and `Request.Url.PathAndQuery`.

**UPDATE**
In order to use `System.Web.Webpages` assembly you should download `System.Web.Webpages` version 3 assembly [from nuget page](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages/). The easiest way to install it, just paste `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages` in **Package Manager Console** in Visual Studio.

Comment: yes, thanks. Basically somewhere in Chapter 8 of his book

Comment: So still I didn't understand "what should I do" to get it working just like his code and not by what I prefixed it with? Should I install that NuGet package you mean?

Comment: @Bohn You should download System.Web.Webpages version 3 assembly from nuget. I specified a link on nuget in my answer, near the NuGet word. The easiest way to install it, just just paste **Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages** in Package Manager Console.